# C++ Error C2061 - typdef definition

Tags: c++, typedef, header-files

In my c++ application I have aaa.h file which has this definition in it:

```
typedef struct 
{
   int a;
   int b;
} CCC;

typedef struct _DDD
{
   unsigned int e;
   CCC cccArray[100];
} DDD;
```

in my aaa.cpp I write:

```
#include "aaa.h"

DDD * dddPtr
```

but then I got this error:
Error c2061: syntax error: identifier 'DDD'

can you please help with this issue?

thanks

Comment: **1.** `_DDD` is not a legal identifier (it starts with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, so it's reserved for the comiler and standard library) - try changing it. **2.** Why are you doing this in the first place? In C++, structure tags do not have a separate pool of names, they are normal names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++ you don't need that `typedef`'ed `struct` - just do this:

```
struct CCC
{
   int a;
   int b;
};

struct DDD
{
   unsigned int e;
   CCC cccArray[100];
};
```

and this:

```
#include "aaa.h"

DDD * dddPtr = NULL;    // or = new DDD;
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing: you should terminate the declaration with a semicolon `;`.

Second: In your case, there is no need for `typedef`s in C++, just define `class`es or `struct`ures:

```
struct CCC
{
   int a;
   int b;
};

struct DDD
{
   unsigned int e;
   CCC cccArray[100];
};

int main()
{
    DDD * dddPtr;
}
```

EDIT: Moreover, you should make sure that each member is properly initialized by providing suitable constructors for `CCC` and `DDD`.